# Where put a common value object between two bounded contexts?

Tags: domain-driven-design

i'm trying to apply the domain driven design in a little project 
i want to separate the authentication of rest of the users logic, 
i'm using a value object for the id (userID) in the beginning i have the userID in the same level(package) of the users but I realize when i separate bounded context for authentication and user, they share a common value object for the userID, so my question is where supose that i have to put the common or share value objects? is correct if i created a packages called commons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages called "common" usually refers to reusable concepts that you use in your projects, so that you don't have to code them in every project. There it's usual to put base abstract objects and interfaces, for entities, value objects, etc.

But it's not your case about userId. What you are saying is to put userId in a "shared kernel" model. It is an option, but usually it is not recommended.

From my point of view:

The auth BC has the concepts id,login,password,role,etc.

The user BC has concepts like name,surname,address,age,etc, but it also has to have the id, that it gets from auth BC.

From what I know, you have 2 options:

(1) Authentication BC shares "id" concept explicitly, i.e. it has a shared kernel. So "id" concept would belong to user BC model too.

(2) Authentication BC is a generic BC. So you have to integrate the user BC with the auth BC to get the id from it.

Comment: How can a BC be a shared kernel at the same time? BCs are meant to isolate everything inside from the outside and only communicate via domain events with other BCs.

Comment: I mean the BC model would be a shared kernel. A shared kernel is a model shared by multiple BCs. It's a way of integrating BCs, an strategic pattern, that couples BCs the most, since they share a model. Apart from this, your comment: "only communicate via domain events with other BCs"... this is not true, events are a way but not the only one (for example, they can communicate with remote calls). Anyway, either events or calls, they are implementation details of integration, they are not patterns. Shared kernel is a pattern (amongst others) for integrating BCs.

Comment: But aren't BCs not supposed to know about each other's inner workings? Because going by that definition, a shared kernel is not a BC in the DDD sense. It's a shared kernel, but that's it. I agree with the rest you said.

Comment: My mistake writing. Auth BC isn't a shared kernel. The shared kernel is the BC model (or just a part of it). But in this case, the BC has to share it, it isn't inner. That's why it is a shared (model) kernel. It has to be shared with other BCs, otherwise it wouldnt be a shared kernel. See page 92 in Vaughn Vernon red book, "Implementing DDD". Gonna edit my answer to be more clear and I won't say the whole BC is a shared kernel, which was my mistake.

Answer (score 8):

It is recommended to not share models between bounded contexts, however, you can share IDs and even simple Value objects (like `Money`).

The general rule is that **you may share anything that is immutable** or that changes very infrequently and IDs rarely change structure (here immutability refers to the source code and value immutability).

Comment: Sorry for the late question, but does that means that we can use `Auth\Domain\Model\UserId` value object in a `Blog\Domain\Model\Post` when referencing the id of the user that created the blog post? Or should we have a local `Blog\Domain\Model\UserId` object? If later, how should we maintain the same identifier validity that is checked in the UserId from the Auth context?

Comment: @KanstantsinK. You can use the same class for the ID. It's not so smart to duplicate every tiny class in the other bounded contexts just to say you follow DDD. IDs are like primitive values. By using the same class you make the dependency explicit, which is always required in a good architecture.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I personally see this as an context mapping question at code level, where you are effectively looking to have a shared kernel between multiple bounded contexts.

This depends on the business really. You typically need to consider the following questions:

- How do different teams responsible for each bounded context collaborate with each other? If it's 1 team maintaining all the related bounded contexts, it might be OK, but it's multiple teams have different objectives, it leads to the next point.
- How do you plan to maintain this shared kernel over time? In general, this shared kernel will need to change to adapt to business changes.

For more detailed arguments, there are plenty of resources out there about context mapping, such as Vaughn Vernon's book "Implementing Domain Driven Design".